# Easiest way to listen to analog connection?

Tags: analog-to-digital

I got a [MAX 9814](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1713) but quickly realized the output is analog and not digital. I found that I could get an Arduino Nano/Micro and connect it to my Pi via a USB to USB-micro cable but I wonder if there's something more compact or simpler that I can do?

To make this question deterministic how would you go about solving this problem? I come from a background of not knowing about how to convert the signals but can solder just fine.

Comment: Not sure what you really want to know.  You can buy ADCs (such as the MCP3xxx series) but they would need to be mounted on a circuit board and connected to the Pi.  I'm not sure what you find simple or for that matter what you find compact.

Comment: Hi Joan! I honestly don't even know what an ADC is! I'd really take any suggestion.

Comment: Get a USB sound card and connect a microphone to it? What exactly do you want to do with the mic?

Comment: I want to use the specific microphone component from Adafruit that I mentioned/linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a complete noob here when it comes to electrical engineering, what I needed was an "Analog to Digital Converter" abbreviated as ADC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter

This is necessary as output from the microphone is going to be continuous, i.e. anywhere between `0.0` to `1.0` inclusive. This will be 'discretized' by sampling the values and converting to `1` and `0` integers to be read by the Raspberry Pi.